# python - outgoing bandwidth for public ips

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, devops

I am using the below line of code to check the total bytes sent out of my centos box

```
import psutil
psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
```

I want to perform this just for the public IP. In other words, I want to calculate outgoing bandwidth just for public IP.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import ipaddress
import psutil

net = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)

for name, interface in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
    for address in interface:
        try:
            network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(f'{address.address}\{address.netmask}')
            if not network.is_private and not network.is_reserved:
                print(net[name].bytes_sent)
                break
        except ValueError as e:
            # these would be eg MAC addresses or similar
            pass
```

Comment: There is nothing called ethernet and ethernet2, I am getting ens4,ens5, and lo! How I will know which one is for public address.

Comment: Correct. Ethernet and Ethernet 2 are the names of my (windows) interfaces. Are you running this in arbitrary environments? If so, you'll need some logic related to routing and so forth to determine the "public" interface. You're using the word "public" here, but I wonder if that's what you mean. Public would mean a publicly addressable/routable IP -- you might actually be looking for the WAN or uplink interface which may or may not be public. I've updated the answer to print for every interface with a public IP.

Comment: its giving me syntax error for the line if not ipaddress.ip_address(f'{address.address}/{address.netmask}').is_private:

Comment: so, what if I don;t know the interface. I mean if i want to make it dynamic lets say if any ip which is not startingwith 10.0.0.0 its public

Comment: @kerasbaz...Can you please help me with the error here and also I don't know the interface.

Comment: Can you try this with the corrected code and let me know what if any error you're getting?

Comment: Ths line sis giving me syntax error :- network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(f'{address.address}\{address.netmask}')      Also, You have mentioned assuming you knwo the interface. I dont knwo the interface because if i knew interfaces i can easipy get the bytes through psutil

Comment: I changed the code after you said you didn't know the interface, but neglected to update that comment in the answer. What version of python are you using that you're getting syntax error from `network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(f'{address.address}\{address.netmask}')`? This works in my python 3.8.5. Can you please provide a traceback?