# How to print public network interface names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, psutil

I want to know which interface on my centos box is public. I am using the below code to get list of all the interfaces:

```
import psutil
psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
```

it gives me an output like below:-

```
{'ens4': snetio(bytes_sent=451795206850898, bytes_recv=282993376354381, packets_sent=2467559041353, packets_recv=1909886336553, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0), 

'ens5': snetio(bytes_sent=686206758798, bytes_recv=468470603173, packets_sent=1233102227, packets_recv=1545708349, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0), 

'lo': snetio(bytes_sent=23027715005, bytes_recv=23027715005, packets_sent=44148705, packets_recv=44148705, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0)}
```

I want to know which one is public and which one is private:

Here I know ens4 is public, ens5 is private and lo is the loopback.

How I can do that with python?

As of now, I am using a bash command which is giving me the output:

```
ip -o addr show scope global | awk '{split($4, a, "/"); print $2" : "a[1]}' | grep -v -E '192\.168|10\.|172\.1[6789]\.|172\.2[0-9]\.|172\.3[01]' | awk '{print $1'}
```

Output:

```
ens4
```

How I can convert the bash command into something in python?

Comment: I answered this question *for you* here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497703/python-outgoing-bandwidth-for-public-ips -- That solution is already checking for private IPs using the ipaddress package.

Comment: @kersbaz your solutio is not working! I commented on your answer but you never responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is, to call the command using os:

```
import os
os.system('ip -o addr show scope global | awk \'{split($4, a, "/"); print $2" : "a[1]}\' | grep -v -E \'192\\.168|10\\.|172\\.1[6789]\\.|172\\.2[0-9]\\.|172\\.3[01]\' | awk \'{print $1\'}')
```